# how to find nearest neighbor values of value inside python list

Tags: python

I have a list of decimal numbers. How can I query between which two values a value falls closest to, giving breakpoints?
my list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7....,999] and value=54,923 which python code returns value between 54 and 55? Also giving the closest Values: (54,55)

Comment: Could you please clarify the problem? what does `54923` have to do with being between `53` and `55`?

Comment: 54.923 my mistake

Comment: Thanks Paul, is this list always sorted?

Comment: yes, sorted. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `54.923` be between `54` and `55`? Or do you only want the odd numbers bounding a given number?

Comment: Value fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way which should be more efficient than a `for` loop:

```
from bisect import bisect_right

# value = 54.923
# my_list = [1, 2, 3, ... 999]

# right = the index of the first number in my_list that is larger than value
right = bisect_right(my_list, value)

# Case where value is in my_list
if my_list[right - 1] == value:
    bounds = [my_list[right - 1]]

# No lower bound or upper bound
elif right == 0:
    bounds = ["No lower bound", my_list[right]]
elif right == len(my_list):
    bounds = [my_list[right - 1], "No upper bound"]

# value is in between 2 values in my_list
else:
    bounds = [my_list[right - 1], my_list[right]]
```

The output is `[54, 55]`.

Comment: As with one of the other answers, this will produce incorrect results if the first entry in the list is greater than *value*

Comment: @LancelotduLac thanks for pointing that out! I've now edited the answer to include the cases where `value` is larger than or less than all elements in `my_list`, and where `value` is in `my_list`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple iteration:

```
def query(lst, target):
    if target < lst[0] or target > lst[-1]:
        # Target is out of list
        return None

    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] > target:
            return [lst[i-1], lst[i]]
    return None
```

```
>>> query([1, 2, 3], 2.5)
[2, 3]
```

---

If your list is always in the form `[1,2,3,4 ... n]`, and the target is a non-whole decimal:

This is the quickest method:

```
from math import ceil, floor

def query(target):
    """Lst must be a list of sequential integers"""
    return [floor(target), ceil(target)]
```

```
>>> query(2.5)
[2, 3]
```

---

For checking if the value is in the list as well:

```
def query(lst, target):
    if target < lst[0] or target > lst[-1]:
        # Target is out of list
        return None

    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] == target:
            return [target]
        if lst[i] > target:
            return [lst[i-1], lst[i]]
    return None
```

Comment: This won't work if the first entry in the list is greater than the target value

Comment: fixed, editing now

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of integers sorted in ascending order and trying to find values either side of some other value you could do this:

```
list_ = [i for i in range(100)]

def find_nearest(list_, n):
    for x, y in zip(list_, list_[1:]):
        if x == n:
            return n, n
        if y > n:
            return x, y

print(find_nearest(list_, 42.5))
```

**Output:**

(42, 43)

You might need to change the logic for the case where *n* is equal to an entry in the list. What values would you return then?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, if n is equal to an entry in the list. How can the function return the value to which it is equal? Best regards

Comment: @PaulErdos, you could use `target in lst`

Comment: Test for equality and return a 2-tuple where both values are the same. So given the list in my answer and search for 42 then return (42, 42). I'll edit the code accordingly

Comment: As @FreddyMcloughlan has said, you could use *in* to scan the list initially. The problem with that is that it's inefficient if the value isn't in the list. *in* knows nothing about order and will therefore have to scan the entire list

Comment: Or you could scan the list as you check for the adjacent values as well, as seen in my edit. But this still has the same issue. But the time taken will be reduced as you are checking both at once, and if one succeeds, the other is halted